# with gluonhq charm down, how to use InAppBillingService for "discussing" with Google Play

Tags: google-play-services, in-app-billing, gluon, gluon-mobile, google-play-developer-api

I want to connect my Javafx product to Googe Play store. To do that, I included the gluon plugin in-app-billing. But, for using this service, I only found this example from http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/4.4.1/com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/InAppBillingService.html

This example provide some information to do that but they do not completely explain the billing and purchase mechanisms with Google Play, "in the context gluon".
Could I get a Java code example that provides the mechanisms to bill and purchase?

That would cover these questions:
- how to initiate a connection with Google Play with keys, ....
- how to purchase a product
- how to know if the product was already bought, before?
- ....

Thanks

Note that this example provide some idea about what to do, but unfortunatley it is not accurate enough:
 - productList is not defined. It is related to productDetails by which way?
 -  replace "finishedProduct.getTitle()" BY "finishedProduct.getDetails.getTitle()"
 - idem with boughtProduct
 - product1 in "Worker order = service.order(product1);" is undefined. Replace "product1" by "product" seems to be fine?
 - the private method "order" is not syntaxically correct
 - and the string androidBase64LicenseKey is not defined (but that is normal :) )

Answer (score 1):

[InAppBillingSample](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/tree/master/InAppBillingSample) is a full working sample that shows how the in-app billing Down service can be used to add purchases to your app has just been released.

**In-App Billing service**

The Charm Down [service](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down/src/default/plugins/plugin-in-app-billing/) is be added to the app, along with the Settings one.

[image: Down services]

The main parts of this service are:

*Retrieve products*

When the app starts, you can retrieve the exiting products:

```
Worker<List<Product>> productDetails = service.fetchProductDetails();
```

and on succeed, process them accordingly:

```
createProductGrid(productDetails.getValue());
```

In this case, the products will show up at the bottom of the view, with a button to purchase them if possible:

[image]

*Buying a product*

If the user decides to buy a product, the order is processed:

```
Worker<ProductOrder> order = service.order(product);
```

When the order is successfully processed, we call `finish` to complete the order:

```
Worker<Product> finish = service.finish(order.getValue());
```

and on succeed you get the purchased product:

```
Product finishedProduct = finish.getValue();
...
player.boughtHealthPotion();
```

**Sample Setup**

The setup for Android and iOS requires that you enter the Google Play Developer console or the Apple App Store Connect and register some products for in-app purchase.

In this sample, these products are:

```
com.gluonhq.inappbilling.health_potion (consumable product)
com.gluonhq.inappbilling.wooden_shield (non consumable product)
```

[image: in-app products]

Providing some details, like price, name or description:

[image: details]

For Android, you also need from the Google Play developer account the base64-encoded RSA public key, that has to be copied to `PlayerService`:

```
private static final String BASE_64_ANDROID_PUBLIC_KEY = "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG*******DAQAB";
```

Note that to test the apk/ipa you need to do release/distribution, so the app has to be signed properly.

**Desktop**

On desktop the in-app billing service won't work but you can test the app so far.

[image]

The sample has a player that can fight and on every fight loses some health (starting from 10).

When you run out of health, you can buy a health potion, or you can also use a wooden shield to reduce the health lost on each fight. This works only on mobile of course.

And you can see the inventory you have:

[image]

**Mobile**

When you run the app on Android or iOS, you can buy at any time the consumable products, and only once the non consumable ones.

[image]

When testing there is no charge involved when you do the purchased:

On Android:

[image]

or on iOS:

[image]

Once you have some items purchased, you can consume then from the inventory:

[image]

Comment: José: with your accurate explanation, I have included without problem this billing API in my code. Thanks a lot. Could you explain now how did you test your code questionning the Google Play server? For my part, by using your API, I can't discuss with the Google Play server. In other words, "PlayerService.getInstance().getService().ifPresent(service ->" works BUT then the related service is never ready. How can we debug a code with a distant server that we cannot get any information about the problem?

Comment: By referring to the InAppBillingSample project and its BasicView file, the service is correctly instantiate and initialized. But then, the service is never ready:
         PlayerService.getInstance().getService().ifPresent(service -> {
            if (service.isReady()) {
                updateProductDetails(service);
            } else {
                service.readyProperty().addListener(...() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue ...) {
                        if (newValue) {
                            updateProductDetails(service)

Comment: The public_key and the product are well defined before

Comment: José: I don't see, in your example, the case in which the Google Play server does not respond. What happens, in this case? As my application is Freemium, the solution would be to go in a degraded mode (for instance, the demo). But, to do that, I should use an information (about the "no server response") coming from your solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: In BasicView.java file,line 177, the test "product.equals(InAppProduct.WOODEN_SHIELD.getProduct()" does not work due to the fact that the data structures are not the same.

For solving that, the test must be applied on the product IDs as follows:

if (product.getID().equals(InAppProduct.WOODEN_SHIELD.getProduct().getID()) &&.....{
                buy.setDisable(true);
            }

This modification should be applied in any case of comparison on the product reference (ex: line 90 of PlayserService.java) - Regards

Comment: The `equals` works precisely on the Product's id, as you can see [here](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down/src/tip/plugins/plugin-in-app-billing/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/inappbilling/Product.java#lines-89).